# Python package obfuscation

Tags: python

How can I obfuscate project package developed in python 3.x so that the functions work the same way before obfuscation. Also the folder structure should be maintained after obfuscation.

Comment: Consider using Cython - to compile some/all modules into a binary file.
That's quite hard to "de-obfuscate".
This is however not the best of Cython usage.

Comment: I have used Cython and successfully created the package. Now I want to import the modules inside robot file. But I am facing issue relative path while importing the .pyd library inside robot file. If both are in same folder, the scripts are executing. Do you have any suggestions on this?